# Using differences between features in different periods as features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, feature-engineering

I have a classifer (XGBOOST) that should predict a user that subscribes to a website.

The dataset that the model is trained on is tabular and labeled. Each user (observation) has a single row in the dataset. However, I check the user behavior in the last weeks before his last action, and each week has the same features. For example, I check how many times he logged in the last week (week_zero), a week before (week_1), etc. A toy example of the data set:
[image]

I do feature engineering on each set of features and calculate the min, max, mean, sum, and standard deviation of each feature set. For example:
[image]

**Is it a good idea to add the difference between the periods as features**?
For example to add difference_log_in_amount_0_1, differnce_log_in_amount_1_2, difference _log_in_amount_0_2 and etc. for example:
[image]

*In my opinion (I'm also the domain expertise)the difference between periods may be relevant*

Comment: (1) What kind of model are you training? (2) Do you have a reason, based on domain-expertise, to believe that this difference between periods is strongly relevant?

Comment: 1. XGBOOST CLASSIFER  2.  I don't know if it is strongly relevant, but it is for sure relevant.

Comment: Please edit your question with those precisions.